# jquery vs php pros / cons on include files

Tags: php, jquery

**Which is the better way of using when you try to include files or contents from other files ?**

In php we have

```
include_once('header.php');
```

In jquery we have

```
$('#header').load('header.html');
```

Comment: They are completely different. It's like comparing apples to oranges. You need to use whichever works for your specific use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One is server-side while the other is client-side so it depends on your use cases.

- Server-side (PHP): This approach allows you to compose the page on the server and return a single HTTP response to the client. An advantage of this approach is that this can support clients that don't have JavaScript enabled.
- Client-side (jQuery): This approach breaks up the content into different HTTP requests from the client. An advantage loading files client-side is that the browser can cache the HTML so if it's being loaded on many pages across the site, subsequent page loads will be smaller and latency will be reduced.